# AI program to generate paragraph pattern

Tags: artificial-intelligence, design-patterns

Is there any software or service or AI program who can rebuild an English paragraph using different set of vocabulary, grammar rules etc.

I mean to say, if the source paragraph is

> “Gwalior is a good tourist place near
>   to Jhansi. Jhansi is very famous due
>   their queen Rani Laxmi Bai
>   (Manikandana)”

Any software can generate its version or pattern like

> “Rani Laxmi Bai (Manikandana) was the
>   queen of Jhansi which is nearer to a
>   good tourist palace Gwalior.”

Or something else. I know that 100% correctness is not possible until human intervention.

Comment: So you want something that you can call do to this, not a way to do it yourself?

Comment: yes. Otherwise with my less intervention.

Comment: You might want to start by finding software that can diagram the sentence.

Comment: +1 to @JoshRoss to suggest very good keywords for further searching

Comment: I suppose diagramming the sentence have some words in advance and form a sentence or group of sentence accordingly. Although this distracted me for a while from what i was searching for. I am searching for a tool who can reform a sentence from sentence itself. And their meaning should not be retain same or closure to similar.

Comment: @articlestack: look up "markov chains" and their application to text generation.

Comment: Maybe I'm cynical, but it sounds like someone's trying to fool a plagiarism scanner.

Comment: http://www.seventhsanctum.com/generate.php?Genname=storygen... randomness is the key., I guess

Comment: Great way to make a cheap link/content farm and don't be detected by Google!

Comment: Look for a program called "rapid rewrite". It's also known as "Spinning" the words in SEO world

Comment: Any development can be used with negative intention. However this is just a programmer's craziness. And it could be a curiosity/path to lead some irregular developments.

Comment: @Jason +1 for good keywords suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rapid Rewrite is a software that can do what you want: http://www.rapidrewriter.com/?hop=qushy It's not free though, and the website is terrible.

Here's another one - same story
http://thebestspinner.com/?id=eprocent

watch their video and tell me that's not what you are looking for...

Comment: Until or unless is try it once i can't be ensured about their claim. Is there any online demo application/tool to test rapid rewriter.

Answer (score 4):

[This guy](http://lurkertech.com/corpspeak/) wrote a JavaScript app that generates corporate bullshit ready for distribution (He's also got a great [buzzword bingo generator](http://lurkertech.com/buzzword-bingo/)). It's not AI, it just simply follows linguistic rules. From what I understand of your question, you don't need AI, you could learn a lot from just studying what this guy did. He seeds the program with nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, etc and generates text that your eyes can parse (it's grammatical but it doesn't necessarily make sense). If you're looking for something to write your thesis paper, you have a lot more looking to do.

From you're question, it looks like you're also looking for a program to parse English and generate the seed data for the formerly mentioned generator. [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) uses [such a grammar parser](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/) for grammar checking. I haven't looked at it in much depth, but I figure you could easily use it to list the parts of speech contained in a section of text. If you used this program to generate the seed data you could pump the output directly into the other program to generate more text.

Comment: i would appreciate your suggestion. But NLP is different than i need.

Comment: You could use my suggestions in combination with a list of English synonyms and possibly alternative grammatical structures. Again, this doesn't require AI, just a well thought-out algorithm and a little leg work on your part.

Answer (score 2):

The python NLTK library does natural language parsing, including building parse trees which include whether a word is a verb, noun, tense etc. Perhaps you could take these trees and re-organize them according to some simple rules you come up with and verify. I don't think you would need too many rules before the results of your program are very different from the source document. Some example rules:

- Replace words with synonyms
- active voice to passive voice and vice-versa (The hunter saw the deer -> the deer was seen by the hunter)

http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Your suggestion seems useful to me. So +1. And i hope to accept it as answer in few days after experiencing the NTLK

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links to various programs to alter written text.  One of them should be able to provide you with some tips on how to implement what you're looking for.

- http://www.worldlingo.com/ma/enwiki/en/Jive_filter
- http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/476939-filters-like-old-skool-jive-fudd-valspeak-text-transformation-python
- http://www.rinkworks.com/dialect/

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that NLP is not the path you need to follow.

However, if you don't want to go the NLP route, you could generate some good sounding sentences without using NLP, by training a custom language model using n-grams to build a fourth or fifth order model.  You would then use statistical probability to generate your sentences.

Once you have your model, you randomly pick a starting word (in the domain of known sentence starting words, or words that begin with a capital letter), and then use conditional probablitily to pick the next word.

An easy example of this is in this article: [Wordmills are coming...](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/wordmills.aspx)

Of course, you would need ample training material in order to accomplish this, as just training on a simple paragraph would not work well for the way you want to rephrase a paragraph.  Without using NLP techniques to detect nouns, verbs, etc. from your sample paragraph (which would require well trained models as well), and then rearranging them using an opposite sentence structure would be more effort than just using NLP in the first place.

What you are trying to do is perform entity extraction, and also location awareness.  Not only that, but relationships between entities and locations.  A very tall order if you are not going to use any NLP.

Comment: Understanding the near about meaning of a sentence and act accordingly is possible with NLP. But rewriting the sentence without changing its meaning seems impossible....at least this time. Although thanks for your advice

Comment: Actually, I demonstrated the opposite.  Taking an input and generating a LIKELY output is possible, but not realistic without a model to validate against.  Either way, you are stuck with generating models.